# AutoMapper - Is it possible to access the source object in AddTransform?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'd like to check if a property is still null after a generic `ResolveUsing` using a `IMemberValueResolver`. I tried `AfterMap` but it did not apply after a `ResolveUsing` on a collection, so I thought that `AddTransform` might be more appropriate.

Based on the [existing AutoMapper unit tests](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/IntegrationTests/ValueTransformers/ValueTransformerTests.cs), I can see that it is possible to override the destination property:

```
p.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
   .ForMember(d => d.Value, opt => opt.AddTransform(d => d + ", seriously"));
```

Would it be possible to get access to the source object inside `AddTransform` to extract a value from that object to override the destination?

This is what I'm basically trying to do:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Description, opts =>
    {
        opts.ResolveUsing<LocalizeResolver, ResourceType>(src => src.ResourceType);
        opts.AddTransform(d => "whatever"); // src.Description??
    })
    .AfterMap((src, dst) => {
        // this never works
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dst.Description))
        {
            dst.Description = src.Description;
        }
    });
```

Comment: "I tried AfterMap but it did not apply after a ResolveUsing on a collection". This works for me. Can you supply all the code that isn't working.

Comment: You are completely right. The full code is https://dotnetfiddle.net/72hoaU. Thx. I was being a muppet.

Comment: Can you open a GitHub issue? The value transformers are pretty basic right now so I'm trying to gather usage to see how they should be enhanced.

Comment: Hi @JimmyBogard. Thx for continuing effort on this project. It does actually work. User error on my part. :-)